# Error al adjuntar archivo al enviar correo por Gmail en Android 11 - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, email

Mi programa envía un documento .txt por correo por medio de un Intent, siempre me ha funcionado el código como lo tengo pero si uso mi app en Android 11 no me adjunta el archivo en Gmail, apps como outlook si lo adjunta, pero en Gmail me aparece "Coulnd't attach the file", mientras en versiones anteriores si lo hace, ¿Alguna Solución?
(Nota: Obviamente solicito permisos al usuario para acceder al almacenamiento pero no veo necesario incluir su código).

Solicito permiso en el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Y esta es mis clase de envío y generación del archivo:

```
String CARPETA_PRINCIPAL = "CarpetaGenerada/";
String CARPETA_DOCTXT = "ArchivosGenerados";
String DIRECTORIO_TXT = CARPETA_PRINCIPAL + CARPETA_DOCTXT;


public void enviarCorreo() {
    String nombre_completo = exportarTxt();
    if (!nombre_completo.equals("")){
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Archivo de Exportación");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enviado desde mi App");
        File file = new File(nombre_completo);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Enviar Correo"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No fué posible obtener el archivo generado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String exportarTxt(){
    String nombreArchivo = "archivo.txt";
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DIRECTORIO_TXT);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    nombre_completo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + DIRECTORIO_TXT + File.separator + nombreArchivo;

    File outputFile = new File(nombre_completo);
    if (outputFile.exists()) {
        outputFile.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bw.write("Hola");
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error: ",String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return nombre_completo;
}
```

La ruta generada es algo como esto, según yo es correcta, ya que repito, en apps como outlook si me lo acepta

> /storage/emulated/0/CarpetaGenerada/ArchivosGenerados/archivo.txt

Answer (score 1):

Si funcionaba sin problema y ahora falla en android 11, debes revisar:

[Visibilidad del paquete en Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)

> Con nuestro enfoque continuo en la privacidad, estamos introduciendo
> cambios sobre cómo las aplicaciones pueden consultar e interactuar con
> otras aplicaciones instaladas en el mismo dispositivo en Android 11.
> En particular, estamos brindando un mejor acceso a la lista de
> aplicaciones instaladas en un determinado dispositivo.

> Para proporcionar una mejor responsabilidad para el acceso a las
> aplicaciones instaladas en un dispositivo, las aplicaciones destinadas
> a Android 11 (nivel de API 30) verán una lista filtrada de
> aplicaciones instaladas de forma predeterminada. Para acceder a una
> lista más amplia de aplicaciones instaladas, una aplicación puede
> especificar información sobre las aplicaciones que necesitan consultar
> e interactuar directamente. Esto se puede hacer agregando un elemento
> `<queries>` en el manifiesto de Android.

Dentro e tu `AndroidManifest.xml`  agrega:

```
   <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Revisando la documentación me doy cuenta que efectivamente, lo de las queries es necesario pero aún así continúa sin funcionar sólo en Gmail, revisando más profundamente incluso hay un ejemplo en el que el Intent se realiza de la misma forma en que lo hago yo, ¿Es posible que el problema sea la ruta? ¿El archivo? Encontré algo de un "FileProvider" ¿Podría ser eso?

Comment: Hola Humberto, es muy importante revisar el LogCat que mensaje se registra, puede ser como comentas la ruta incorrecta.